# How to use well-ordering to form a "least counterexample derived contradiction" to prove rule for obtaining the remainder when dividing $3^n$ by 13?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, order-theory

By the division with remainder theorem, we know that there exists $q \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $r \in \mathbb{Z}$, where $0 \leq r < 13$, such that:
                    \begin{equation*}
                       3^n = 13q + r
                    \end{equation*}

**Simple rule for obtaining remainder when dividing $3^n$ by $13$:** it can be shown then, that $r = 3^p$, where $p = \min R$, where $R = \{m \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}\ | n \equiv m(3)\}$. A remark to explain the modulo notation I am using:

\begin{equation*}
a \equiv b (c) = \exists q \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ s.t. } a - b = qc
\end{equation*}

I know I can use induction to prove the simple rule, but I'd like to draw upon another fact: subsets of the integers with a lower bound are well ordered. This well-ordering is equivalent to induction.

I am trying to practice proofs using this equivalence between well-ordering and induction, but am still having some trouble. Here is what I have so far:

1) We know that $R$ has a minimal element since it is bounded below since $R \subset \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$. Let $p = \min R$.

2) Pick an assumption involving $p$ along with 1), which results in the conclusion that $p \neq \min R$, resulting in a contradiction. What should this assumption be? $r \neq 3^p$?

We know that $r \neq 3^p$ is equivalent to saying $r < 3^p \;\vee\; r > 3^p$. Consider the first case:

\begin{align*}
r > 3^p \implies 3^n < 13q + 3^p...  
\end{align*}

This seems like a pretty big dead-end. What might I try instead, and more importantly, what is the moral of the story in terms of picking least counter-examples in the future?

Comment: The particular problem you're looking at is full of all sorts of details. I suggest you start by writing out clear explanations of why induction on naturals is equivalent to well-ordering of the naturals, without looking at any proofs you've already seen of this. You should then be able to *use* your explanations to transform proofs of specific claims from one style to the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: The statement $P(n)$ (for $n\in\Bbb Z_{\ge 0}$) that you’re trying to prove is:

> $P(n)$: If $r=\min\{m\in\Bbb Z_{\ge 0}:m\equiv n\pmod3\}$, then there is a $q\in\Bbb Z$ such that $3^n=13q+r$.

The set to which you want to apply the well ordering principle is therefore

$$B=\{n\in\Bbb Z_{\ge 0}:P(n)\text{ is false}\}\;,$$

the set of ‘bad’ $n$, not $\{m\in\Bbb Z_{\ge 0}:m\equiv n\pmod3\}$ for some particular $n\in\Bbb Z_{\ge 0}$.

The idea is to assume that $B\ne\varnothing$ and derive a contradiction, thereby showing that $B=\varnothing$ and hence that $P(n)$ holds for each $n\in\Bbb Z_{\ge 0}$.

If $B\ne\varnothing$, then there is a smallest $n\in B$. Now argue almost exactly as you would for the proof by induction.

- $n$ can’t be $0$; why?

Therefore $n-1\ge 0$, so $n-1\notin B$, and therefore $P(n-1)$ holds.

- Show that $P(n)$ holds, so that $n\notin B$, thereby getting the desired contradiction.

Comment: I'm glad to see your name again in these parts!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. After I proved well ordering implies induction for myself again, I was able to make good progress along with your help. I have a question for you however: where you write "...so $n-1 \in B$...", do you mean "...so $n - 1 \not\in B$..."?

Comment: @user89: I do indeed; thanks. Fixed now.