# Well ordering axiom problem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Show that if a and b are positive integers, there is a positive integer n such that $na>b$. Hint: Consider the differences $b-na$, and apply the well ordering axiom.

I have no approach yet. My question is how to show that a set is well ordered.

Comment: It is commonly accepted that the positive integers or "natural numbers" are well-ordered.  This is the purpose of "the well ordering axiom" as normally presented in elementary number theory.  An equivalent statement is that every non-empty set of positive integers will have *a least element*.  So the question you ask in the first paragraph is not the same as "how to show that a set is well ordered".

Comment: how is the given hint useful?

Comment: The hint is suggesting that you construct a set of natural numbers (or positive integers).  Then use the well-ordering axiom to identify that set contains a least element.

Comment: how will the set look like?.

Comment: We do not need induction (well-ordering), for it is easy to verify directly that $(b+1)a\gt b$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: While "induction" is not needed, the exercise seems intended to help students understand the power of the well-ordering of natural numbers (which is roughly equivalent to the induction principle).

Comment: @hardmath: The term induction slipped out, I meant to write well-ordering, and managed to edit in time.  In general, I do not like illustrations of induction in which induction is not really needed, it gives the (powerful and important) notion a bad name.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need to show that any set is well ordered: you just need to use the fact that $\Bbb N$, the set of non-negative integers, is well ordered. This is something that you’re allowed to assume.

HINT: Suppose that there is no such $n$; then $na\le b$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, so $b-na\ge 0$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$. Let $A=\{b-na:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$; $A$ is a non-empty subset of $\Bbb N$, so it has a least element, say $\ell$. Let $m\in\Bbb Z^+$ be such that $\ell=b-ma$. Now consider $b-(m+1)a$ to get a contradiction.

There are other slightly different ways to make use of the fact that $\Bbb N$ is well ordered, but this is one of the most straightforward.

Comment: Now I am starting to see the connection between induction and the well ordering principle. This implies that there is a less least element which can't be possible hence we assume $l$ to be the least element.

Comment: @TheMathNoob: You might find [this question and answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1438878/how-to-use-well-ordering-to-form-a-least-counterexample-derived-contradiction) useful in getting more of a handle on the connection between well ordering and induction.